# Write array to CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

I am trying to insert data into CSV file by storing data into array first before writing to CSV. But I am facing a problem with writing a multidimentional array to CSV file.

Here is how my input looked like :

```
<input type="text" name="names" placeholder="Enter Name" />
<select name="gender">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" />
<input type="text" name="state" placeholder="Enter State" />

<label>How Did You Find Us?</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="remarks[]" value="Search Engine (eg. Google)"> Search Engine (eg. Google) &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="remarks[]" value="Facebook"> Facebook &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="remarks[]" value="Newspaper Ads"> Newspaper Ads &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="remarks[]" value="Bus-Stop Ads"> Bus-Stop Ads &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

The following code is how I store input data and write in CSV file :

```
$names = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "names");
$gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender");
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "age");
$state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "state");
$remarks = $_POST['remarks'];

$inputArr[] = array(
    $names, $gender, $age, $state, $remarks
);

$fp = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/student.csv", "a+");

fputcsv($fp, $inputArr);
fclose($fp);
```

The `$inputArr` output is as follow which is a multidimentional :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Melinda
    [1] => Female
    [2] => 23
    [3] => united state
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Facebook
            [1] => Newspaper Ads
            [2] => Bus-Stop Ads
        )

)
```

I wanted to make the array be like below array so that data can be inserted into CSV, but I don't know how to foreach the array to get the output as follow:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Melinda
    [1] => Female
    [2] => 23
    [3] => united state
    [4] => Array
    [5] => Facebook
    [6] => Newspaper Ads
    [7] => Bus-Stop Ads
)
```

Comment: can you add a small csv sample with the header?

Comment: Remove `$remark` from your `$inputArray` and then use array_merge() to add them instead: `$inputArray = array_merge($inputArrray, $remarks);`. That should create a one dimension array with all the values.

Comment: Btw, your code should produce another level in your current array, since you're using `$inputArr[] = ...` instead of `$inputArr = ...`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson your solution solved my problem. Thank you! You may want to put that as a solution so that I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: You have a couple of answers below that fits the bill, you can accept either of those two. No need to add another answer, doing the same. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_merge`, also I don't think you need `[]` while assigning to `inputArr`:

```
$inputArr = array_merge(array($names, $gender, $age, $state), $remarks);
$fp = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/student.csv", "a+");

fputcsv($fp, $inputArr);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just merge the values before pushing them:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34c3c0860c80c2b8f60ba601c2314418d2d5306d))

```
$names="joe";
$gender="smith";
$age="18";
$state="WA";
$remarks=array('Facebook','Newspaper Ads','Bus-Stop Ads');

$inputArr=array_merge(array($names, $gender, $age, $state),$remarks);
var_export($inputArr);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'joe',
  1 => 'smith',
  2 => '18',
  3 => 'WA',
  4 => 'Facebook',
  5 => 'Newspaper Ads',
  6 => 'Bus-Stop Ads',
)
```